# Joining 2D polylines and DEM into 3D polylines using QGIS/GRASS/SAGA?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, dem, saga

I have a road network in 2D/PostGIS and a DEM. I want to turn the road network into 3D by retrieving the Z-value from the DEM.

Both files are quiet large so an efficient process is needed. I'd prefer to use QGIS or any other open source tool.

Answer (score 3):

For that, you can use

- [GRASS GIS](http://grass.osgeo.org/) with [v.drape](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.drape.html): Converts vector map to 3D by sampling of elevation 
  raster map.
- [SAGA GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html)  with Shapes - Grid\Add Grid Values to Shapes
- QGIS with GRASS v.drape in Sextante (QGIS 1.8) or Processing (QGIS 2.0)

[image]

- QGIS with SAGA GIS "Add grid to shapes" in Processing (QGIS 2.0)

[image]

- Python in the Python console with

  raster.dataProvider().identify()

`