# How to prop up/convert a 2D line to 3D using DEM in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, dem

I have planar (2D) polylines, which I'd like to convert to 3D ones using a DEM of the same region. I am wondering if this can be done in PostGIS?

I guess I can program a SQL function that reads all the vertices of a polyline/LineString, and then promotes each vertex to 3D one by one. But I just wanted to ask first to avoid reinventing wheels.

A related question ([Joining 2D polylines and DEM into 3D polylines using QGIS/GRASS/SAGA?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74016)) asked about how to do this in QGIS but I need to work in PostGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Drape lines on a DEM with PostGIS](http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/drape-lines-on-a-dem-with-postgis.html) is a blog posting by Mathieu Leplatre that goes over the options for draping a polyline over a DEM in PostGIS.

You can either assign a Z value to each vertex of the polyline, put a vertex at each change of elevation, or split the difference and sample the DEM and put a new vertex at a set distance from each other.